# Loop do repeat não sai da primeira posição

Tags: r, loop

O exercício é:

Usando a função `repeat`, gere `1000` amostras da distribuição normal, cada uma com tamanho amostral igual `n` e parâmetros de média e desvio padrão iguais a `µ` e `σ`, respectivamente. Escolha os valores para `n`, `µ` e `σ`.

Para cada banco de dados gerado, calcule `Z = (¯x − µ)/(σ/p(n))` em que `x¯` é a média amostral.

Calcule a proporção de amostras que levam a valores para `Z` menores do que `-1,96` ou maiores do que `1,96`.

Estava tentando calcular primeiro `¯x`, mas nem isso consegui.

Segue o código:

```
f10 <- function(n, mean, sigma) {

  lista <- numeric(1000)

  i <- 1

  repeat{

    output <- rnorm(n, mean = mean, sd = sigma)

    lista[i] <- mean(output)

    if(i>1000) break()
  }

  i <- i+1

  return(lista)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O contador precisa estar dentro do `repeat`, antes da verificação da condição:

```
f10 <- function(n, mean,sigma) {
  lista <- numeric(1000)
  i <- 1
  repeat {
    output <- rnorm(n, mean = mean, sd = sigma)
    lista[i] <- mean(output)
    i <- i + 1
    if (i > 1000) break()
  }
  return(lista)
}
```

Como estava, o valor de `i` era sempre 1 ao checar a condição para o `break`.